# School Project : To determine Eq. resistance of a cube whose each edge has a resistor, say R

Tags: resistors, circuit-analysis, design, multimeter, physical-design

**Background**

I am a high school student, we are supposed to submit a Physics Project, individually.
Since I have never done any Electrical Project/Experiment before, I came up with the idea of making a cube of resistors and then finding its equivalent resistance across various points using a Battery, Multimeter, and some piece of wires to form the circuit and thus verifying the theoretical results.

**My Problem**

1. I have never done any electrical experiment/project, ever, except building a circuit to light the bulb using a DC battery and a wire.
2. No help possible from School authorities or Say I do not wish to take any, because I am shy or whatever.
3. I can afford to buy a battery, multimeter and some resistors, but no idea about which one to order to get somewhat accurate enough results, like resistance of what magnitude, 10K or 10, same for battery, since this is just a school thingie, so I wish to buy cheaper stuff and yet get accurate enough results.
   Also how do I form a cube out of resistors, googling and reading suggested me something called souldering but I haven`t ever done it before, so idk how to go about it. Same with the fact that I have no idea on how to use the multimeter.

**Did I try to find answer before Posting this**

Yes I did, and even got a lot of things to know from that, like "carbon" resistors, "souldering" to join the resistors to make the cube and stuff like that, but all that has just not given me clear thoughts on how to proceed.

P.S. I don`t have much time to complete all this :)

Comment: I want this and I want that but I have no clue and oh P.S. I don`t have much time to complete all this :) Then why didn't you start working on this a week ago ??

Comment: I have like 15 days, which isn`t that less I guess. It was intended to convey, the sooner the better :)

Comment: Why build it - just use math and prove it.

Comment: @Andy, I understand that math is enough in this case, but is building it a bad idea, what else do you suggest then, as a good exercise, for learning, as a physics project.

Comment: Between google and common sense, you should be able to figure all this out for yourself. I mean, youtube has dozens of videos on how to use a multimeter, or how to solder. If anything, the question on my mind is why making a resistor cube is supposed to be an acceptable project for physics class. What was the requirements, that you do a project relating to Ohm's Law?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've come up with a neat, creative idea for a science project, and I think it's great that you're interested in electronics. However, in this case, I think you've bitten off more than you can chew - you don't seem to have enough experience in basic things.  Regardless I'll try and give you some starting points:

**Calculating  the Theoretical Resistance of a Cube:**

First off, this is not trivial. You first need to consider what will be you cubes 'input', 'output' and 'ground (0V)'. These points will be arbitrary, but need to be defined. You'll have an equivalent resistance between these points. For simplicity choose your cube to be as small as possible, even 1*1*1 - the problem gets exponentially harder every time you make any dimension longer. To see how quickly this can become complicated for a large number of resistor look here: http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath668/kmath668.htm

Now redraw you cube circuit on paper (noting your input and output points). Wherever 2 or more resistors touch there will be a node. Now use the theory from class to find the equivalent resistance and voltage - lookup Thevenin equivalent.

**Choosing Resistors:**

You will generally want to choose resistances in the values of kilo-ohms. For your purposes cheap carbon film resistors will suffice. Low resistance values will result in too much current flow and things will get hot. (But you might get some interesting transient effects with high current! You could potentially simulate the inductive properties of your geometry due to the EM fields generated ... but I digress).

**"Souldering"**

Actually - Soldering. This is a method of melting down metal to connect electrical components. For your experiment I suggest just tightly twisting the wires/legs of the resistors together. This will provide sufficient electrical contact, wont require you to invest in soldering equipment and will allow you to make a structure relatively easily.

**Battery:**

If you chose high value resistances, any old battery will do. You could even choose several different batteries such as a AAs, 9V etc, and show how the output voltage is proportional to the input voltage.

**Experimental Measurements:**

For your experiential measurements of voltage and resistance you can buy the cheapest digital multimeter you can find. They will all have sufficient accuracy for your needs. However, if you're interested in electronics you might want to spend a little more as it's one of the first tools you'll need as a electronics hobbiest. For voltage, just put multimeter to measure "volts", connect your circuit and put the probes at ground, and the point you've defined as your output. For resistance, put your multimeter in resistance mode and place the probes between your input and output points you've defined.

You have 2 weeks - if you work at it and search on the Internet and are happy to ask your teacher for help calculating the theoretical resistance you could make a nice project.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Using more than 1 batteries sounds a good idea.